# Is there any solution for getting this error Tried calling: findAncestorStateOfType<NavigatorState>()?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to navigate to the another page by using loading dialogue.

```
 waiting(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // return object of type Dialog
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async => false,
          child: AlertDialog(
              key: _keyLoader,
              content: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Text("Loading..."),
                  )
                ],
              )),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Above code is my loading dialogue box.
I want to navigate to another page when onPressed function is called.
When onPressed function is called then below method is called.

```
void _validateInputs(BuildContext context) {
    waiting(context);
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
       setState(() {
        _autoValidate = false;
      });
      
       Navigator.of(_keyLoader.currentContext).pop();
       Navigator.of(context)
                        .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                      return CareerDetailsPage();
                    }));
     

      _formKey.currentState.reset();
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _autoValidate = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

I want to pop this loading dialogue box and navigate to another page.
But I am getting this below type of error.

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The method 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: findAncestorStateOfType<NavigatorState>()
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: did you try `Navigator.of(context).pop()` ?

Comment: yes tried but again same error.

Comment: I do not find any reference of `_validateInputs` in first part of the code.

Comment: I called it from onPressed function of RaisedButton.that's it